# discrete-time (slew) rate limiting algorithm

Tags: derivative

Consider uniformly-spaced samples of smooth, bandlimited signal observed in noise and subject to some artifacts (small jumps).  Physical restrictions impose a constraint on the maximum magnitude of the derivative of the noiseless, "artifactless" signal.  In an effort to smooth the signal and remove artifacts, I could impose this constraint by simply limiting the size of the sample-to-sample change (e.g., [matlab](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/ratelimiter.html), but this seems like it will introduce other effects to compromise the smoothness of the signal.

The only other option I came across are nonlinear feedback loops (e.g., [see this paper](http://www.sierrafoot.org/x-15/documents/AIAA20035463.pdf).  I suppose that one could also impose derivative inequality constraints on, say, some local polynomial representation of the signal as well.  Any other ideas, references, etc?

Thanks!

Comment: can we model the artifacts as additive noise?

Comment: *Physical restrictions impose a constraint on the maximum magnitude of the derivative of the noiseless, "artifactless" signal.* is redundant. You already said it's band-limited.

Comment: The artifacts arise within a sensing mechanism in the form of jumps.  I suppose that you could model this as an additive term that would be formed of some kind of staircase function.

Comment: wait, like quantization noise?

Comment: No. Sorry I wasn't clear enough.  Quantization noise would be a direct function of the signal being quantized together with the quantization scheme.  Imagine a series of monotonically increasing randomly spaced time instances (say from a Poisson process).  At each time instant a step in amplitude is observed that is maintained until the next time instance.  These steps are fairly rare and a significant amount of time could pass between steps.

Comment: Ah, ok! Hm, interesting case.

Comment: Could you please more exactly characterize the jump process? A Poisson process is defined by the rate parameter, which is varying in time in a non-homogeneous Poisson process. Would your signal then be the integral of the rate over time, that is, the expected value of the Poisson process given a fixed starting point? That and the rate would be equally bandlimited.

Answer (score 1):

Like the old German saying goes:

*If you give a man a filter, everything looks like a signal that needs to be low-pass filtered*

or so.

Slew rate and signal bandwidth are closely related. Simply low-pass filter your signal; usually, you'd do that with a linear filter, not an non-linear filter, and especially not a non-linear recursive one, because those are pretty hard to get stable.

By the way, if you look at FIR and IIR filters, you'll notice that we model these in z-Domain as polynomials, but by doing so, we can apply them to the signal in a linear way.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Certainly (linear) low pass filtering will smooth out the jumps.  To know whether the derivative constraint is being respected, I suppose I could calculate the peak sample-to-sample change in the step response of the filter.  It may turn out that the amount of low pass filtering I'd need to do to limit the sample-to-sample change may be too aggressive (I may wind up eliminating desired signal components and/or introducing excessive delay).

Comment: sample-to-sample change is actually you take the current sample, and subtract the previous, right? That would be a FIR filter with taps (depending on which direction you count them) `[-1 1]`, which, by the way, is a high pass filter

Comment: If you take a hpf's output  and subtract that from it's group-delay-delayed input, you'd end up with a LPF

Comment: Yes, but I would implement a low pass filter, calculate the low pass filter's step response (with the largest expected amplitude jump) and determine the largest sample-to-sample change to see if this change exceeds physical limits imposed by the actual signal of interest.  You are right that [-1, 1] is high pass.  I would use this only to analyze the desired filter's step response.

Comment: FWIW, $[1, -1]$ as filter taps approximate a derivative operation on the signal being filtered.  The approximation is best at DC and worst at the Nyquist frequency.

Comment: @AndyWalls true; basically, this "non-perfection" in the derivative is what makes things like Muller&Müller worse than e.g. the Polyphase Filterbank Sync (which approximates $\frac d{d\,t}$ better), compare a [somewhat dated thread](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/discuss-gnuradio/2015-07/msg00610.html) (gosh, was I naive :) ).